# Add model validation to LINQ objects mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

Hi am using Linq to SQL to create objects from my database i.e. Customer.  I then have a model which is like this:

```
public class EventModel{

   public Customer Customer {get;set;}

   public Event Event {get;set;}

}
```

I then have a view which lists the Customer and Event details which can be edited.  My question is how do we add validation on the Customer?  `The Customer.Name` field is a required field but I cannot define this.  Is there any logic that can be used for the system to understand this is a non nullable field from the database?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It probably would be the best to create a dedicated view model (with data/properties you really need) that would be annotated for validation. Well, annotations are the easiest (and built-in) way, you can always use FluentValidation or whatever else you want.

Comment: There must be a nicer implementation that would understand the complexities of the object on the datatype if it was not null would be a good indiation that it was required

Answer (score 0):

Create a partial class for your Customer object and a Metadadata class for it, like following:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

[MetadataType(typeof(CustomerMetadata))]
public partial class Customer
{
    public class CustomerMetadata
    {
        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        // other properties...
    }
}
```

Comment: how would this be used in the MVC model?

Comment: Isn't Customer one of the entities in your Linq-to-SQL?